# Youtube subscribe button not working for my channel

Tags: youtube, subscribe

I am trying to add a youtube subscribe button on my website.

[I picked up code from here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button)

I have used the channel id - **UCYPhPtoN64fI2hfge6Iw_gQ** in the below html code snippet on my website.

```
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="UCYPhPtoN64fI2hfge6Iw_gQ" data-layout="full" data-count="default"></div>
```

I could only see an exclamation mark inside the iframe.

I need help with embedding this subscribe buttion using channel id on a webpage. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`data-channel` is invalid parameter.

You should use `data-channelid` instead.

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/maxim_mazurok/8zkg3ays/)

Comment: Yes I did included the platform.js script. You can try the html snippet I provided. It has a valid channel id.

Comment: @AnshulBajpai I have figured out your problem and updated my answer. Please, accept it, if it helps :)